# Combine two lists while maintaining order and removing duplicates

Tags: python

I'd like to combine two lists while maintaining order and not allowing duplicates.

```
list1 = [4, 5, 2, 6]
list2 = [4, 1, 2, 9, 6]

output -> [4, 5, 2, 6, 1, 9]
```

What I've tried is `list(set(list1) | set(list2))` but this does not maintain order.  Is there a way to do this with list comprehension?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "maintaining order"? I don't think I understand the logic. For instance, why does the 1 come after the 2 in the output, when it comes before the 2 in the input?

Comment: @davedwards that does not maintain order. That sorts it.

Comment: hegash answer got it thanks guys

Comment: Will you ever have duplicates in the first list? If so, not all the answers below are created equal.

Comment: `functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + [y] if y not in x else x, list2, list1)`

Comment: @MykolaZotko highly inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list1 = [4, 5, 2, 6]
list2 = [4, 1, 2, 9, 6]

list3 = [item for item in list2 if item not in list1]

list1 += list3
```

much more readable than using sets

Comment: This is an O(N*M)  solution, but it does work.

Comment: It is inefficient. `list` membership testing takes linear time, and you do that in a loop. So it *scales* poorly, by a factor of the multiple of the size of the two lists. You could get it to scale by just the max size if you want (and can afford auxiliary space to create a set)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `dict.fromkeys` method:

```
list(dict.fromkeys(list1 + list2))
```

If you're using Python 3.6 or earlier versions, you can use `collections.OrderedDict` in place of `dict`.

Comment: How comes that items in the dict are ordered?

Comment: Dict keys are guaranteed to be ordered since Python 3.7. Prior to Python 3.7, one can use `collections.OrderedDict` instead to achieve the same.

Comment: This is a great answer

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following for an *O(n)* solution:

```
list1 = [4, 5, 2, 6]
list2 = [4, 1, 2, 9, 6]

s1 = set(list1)

result = list1 + [e for e in list2 if e not in s1]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[4, 5, 2, 6, 1, 9]
```

Comment: `list1 + [x for x in list2 if x not in list1]` or if you prefer  `list1.extend([x for x in list2 if x not in list1])`

Comment: @hansolo that is not a linear time solution though, it is quadratic (well, O(M*N))